# How do I show that $\frac{M_n-E(M_n\mid F_{n-1})}{\xi_n-E(\xi_n\mid F_{n-1})}$ is predictable?

Tags: probability-theory

Show that $\frac{M_n-E(M_n\mid F_{n-1})}{\xi_n-E(\xi_n\mid F_{n-1})}$ is predictable.

I want to know if this is true, if $M_n$ is martingale adapted to $F_n=\sigma({\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n})$, and $\xi_i$ is iid.

It seems that this is related to the theorem "predictable representation property."
This is essentially the converse of martingale transform. I have been studying this for four hours to no avail.

Could someone give me any insight? Even if it's not the answer, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

I will post the original question if needed. Thank you.